# Referencing primary key in another table with laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, foreign-key-relationship

I am creating tables for a Laravel project using migrations. This is how it will look like:

```
Schema::create( 'table1', function( Blueprint $table ){
    $table->increments( 'id' );
}

Schema::create( 'table2', function( Blueprint $table ){
    $table->increments( 'id' );
}

Schema::create( 'table3', function( Blueprint $table ){
    $table->integer( 'table1_id' )->unsigned();
    $table->integer( 'table2_id' )->unsigned();
    $table->foreign( 'table1_id' )->references( 'id' )->on( 'table1' )->onDelete( 'cascade' );
    $table->foreign( 'table2_id' )->references( 'id' )->on( 'table2' )->onDelete( 'cascade' );
    $table->primary( [ 'table1_id', 'table2_id' ] );
}

Schema::create( 'table4', function( Blueprint $table ){
    // Here is my question
    // How do I reference the primary key on table3??
    $table->whatMethodCreatesTheRightTypeOfColumn( 'table3_id' );
    $table->foreign( 'table3_id' )->references( ???? )->on( 'table3' )->onDelete( 'cascade' );
}
```

I want to create a column that holds the value of the table3 primary key which I guess is an unsigned big integer, but I am not sure. When I go with Integer or unsigned integer I get this:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1239 Incorrect foreign key definition for 'table4_table3_id_foreign': Key reference and table reference don't match (SQL: alter table `table4` add constraint `table4_table3_id_foreign` foreign key (`table3_id`) references `table3` (`table1_id`, `user_id`) on delete cascade)



  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1239 Incorrect foreign key definition for 'table4_table3_id_foreign: Key reference and table reference don't match
```

Comment: I know it's possible to add a second params to the primary()
$table->primary( [ 'table1_id', 'table2_id' ] , $NAME);

Is it possible to  reference that name?

Other suggestion: both foreign() and references() used to accept arrays as well?

So try: $table->foreign( [ 'table1_id', 'table2_id' ]' )->references( [ 'table1_id', 'table2_id' ] )

Does that work?

I will add it as a regular answer, instead of comment....

Comment: Or even something completely different: table3 has a normal id, but make the [ 'table1_id', 'table2_id' ] combination unique() ? Maybe this is a good solution for you?

Comment: The idea was to reference the index instead of a column with a key, but it looks like it is not possible, so I had to create an incremental column and reference that column instead of the index. I will try your suggested solutions to see if one works. Thanks